# Couldn t find the path on server machine

Tags: c#, path, local-network

I have an asp.net project running on local server .

There are two jpg images in "D:\Scan\ScannedDocs\Images". I want merge these images and save to
"D:\BPMSITE\BPM.Marketing\MyFiles\2013_1"  after click of a  button.  Both paths on server machine.

```
System.Drawing.Image imagef = Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\Scan\\ScannedDocs\\Images\\f0000007.jpg");
```

I tried some combinations of this with `"@"`  and `"/"`  but couldn t find the file.

Problem s Source folder out of webroot.

What's the solution?

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure that the files actually exist in the location you are checking?

Comment: What happens when you execute above code? Do you get any errors? Does the file exist? It would be better if you loop through the directory and get the list of files first.

Comment: yes i created all files there s no problem ,if i run program on my computer .the problem s only at server machine

Comment: Does your asp.net application have an access to that file? On server.

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:/Scan/ScannedDocs/Images/f0000007.jpg ,i didn t do anything about accessing the file ,what s the special things to apply on my project?Both paths on the server

Comment: I would double check if you asp.net application has an access to that file. According to FromFile docs it does not throw NoAccess exception, only FileNotFound, where no access may be a subset of not found exception. As far as I remember, I had similar issue.  `D:/Scan/ScannedDocs/Images/` does not look like a path inside your website root and most likely that nobody set permissions for asp.net user to that folder.

Comment: exeption is just FileNotFound.There s no info about accessing.still dont have a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving Permissions to IIS Users is the Solution .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For WebApps to map a relative path you can use the Server.MapPath method, more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx